# How to get raspicam cmake to work with an openCV installation

Tags: opencv, cmake, raspberry-pi3

I struggle to understand how I should do to get raspicam cmake CMakeLists.txt installation example to work together with my openCV installation.

1. First I install a Jessie Pixel SD card.
2. Then I install openCV on this way

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/49668/how-do-i-install-open-cv-easily-onto-my-raspberry-pi-and-so-that-it-works

I was install and compile openCV on a folder I named:

```
/home/pi/OpenCV/opencv-3.2.0/release
```

==== UPDATE Here is the easy solution I was missed ============

After succesfully local installation on my folder
/home/pi/OpenCV/opencv-3.2.0/release
I have also to do this command to share OpenCV thins to the default folder
/usr/local/include
/use/local/lib
how the compiler have a default path to

```
$ sudo make install
```

then OpenCV will be installed in /usr/local/... 
and then raspicam default CMakeLists.txt cmake compilation will work proper

============================================

Then I download raspicam API from:

https://www.uco.es/investiga/grupos/ava/node/40
I follow the compilation guide but It not understand where I should place the PATH related to my OpenCV folder

```
/home/pi/OpenCV/opencv-3.2.0/release
```

I put all the unziped files regarding raspicam API in folder with name

```
/home/pi/raspicam-0.1.3
```

I then do

```
$ mkdir build
$ cd build
$ sudo cmake ..
```

I got this warning/error message when I do my `$ sudo cmake ..`

```
CMake Warning at CMakeLists.txt:51 (FIND_PACKAGE):
  By not providing "FindOpenCV.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "OpenCV" with any
  of the following names:

    OpenCVConfig.cmake
    opencv-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "OpenCV" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "OpenCV_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If    "OpenCV"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

I tried to add `/home/pi/OpenCV/opencv-3.2.0/release` on several places in `CMakeLists.txt`, but it not seems to work proper.

Comment: I have solved the problem by add this on line 28 on the default     CMakeLists.txt from raspicam:     SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} /home/pi/OpenCV/opencv-3.2.0/release)

Answer (score 1):

solved by add this on line 28 on the CMakeLists.txt from raspicam:
    SET(CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH ${CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH} /home/pi/OpenCV/opencv-3.2.0/release)